# React - How do I know which user liked a post?

Tags: reactjs

There you go. When I try to retrieve when loading the page, all the tables of users who liked the posts, that I make the comparisons, that I change the state, it is the states of all the posts that change, without difference. If only one post is liked by the user, all posts are marked as liked. And if I post a new post, all the others are marked as unliked. If I like it, all the others mark liked. I searched, searched, searched, I don't know how to do it.

```js
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false)

    let newArray = []
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isDataLoading) {
            for (let arrayOfLikes of dataResultPosts) {
                newArray.push(arrayOfLikes.usersLiked)
            }
            for (let element of newArray) {
                let userId = element.find((id) => id === dataResult.infos._id)
                if (userId) {
                    setLiked(true)
                    console.log('yes')
                } else if (!userId) {
                    setLiked(false)
                    console.log('no')
                }
            }
        }
    }, [])
```

```
function DisplayPosts(props, index) {

    return (
        <div className="allPostsAndModals" key={Date.now}>
            <div className="blockAuthor">
                <div className="divAuthor">
                    <div className="pictureUserPost">
                        <img
                            id={props.id}
                            src=""
                            className="imageUser"
                        ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="nameAuthor">
                        {props.firstname} {props.lastname}
                    </div>
                    <div className="divIconOptions">
                        <div className="blockIconOptions">
                            <p className="iconOption">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon
                                    icon={faEllipsis}
                                    fontSize="36px"
                                />
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="blockContentPost">
                <div className="paragraphContentPost">
                    {props.postContent} {props.id}
                </div>
                {liked ? <p>Liked ! </p> : <p>Not liked</p>}
            </div>
            <div className="separator"></div>
            <div className="blockImagePost">
                <img
                    className="imagePost"
                    src={props.imageUrlPostPicture || ' '}
                    alt="photo profil utilisateur"
                ></img>
            </div>
            <div className="separator"></div>
            <div className="ContenairOptions">
                <div className="iconLikeOn">
                    <button
                        id={props.id}
                        className="buttonLike"
                        onClick={likeSystem}
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon id={props.id} icon={farThumbsUp} />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div>{props.id}</div>
                <input
                    className="inputLike"
                    defaultValue={props.likes + likeUser}
                ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const postsDisplay = dataResultPosts.map((post) => (
    <DisplayPosts
        firstname={post.firstname}
        lastname={post.lastname}
        postContent={post.postContent}
        imageUrlPostPicture={post.imageUrlPostPicture}
        likes={post.likes}
        key={post._id}
        id={post._id}
    ></DisplayPosts>
))
```

```
    const likeSystem = async (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.id)
        // let inputLike = document.querySelector('#likeInput')
        // inputLike.value = parseInt(inputLike.value) + 1
        // let iconLikeOn = document.querySelector('#iconLikeOn')
        // iconLikeOn.classList.add('iconLikeOn')
        // if (likeUser === 0) {
        //     setLikeUser(1)
        // }
        // // if (likeUser === 1) {
        // //     setLikeUser(0)
        // // }

        let idUrl = e.target.id

        if (likeUser === 0) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    'http://localhost:4200/api/ficheUser/post/like/' + idUrl,
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            userId: authContext.userId,
                            likes: 1,
                        }),
                    }
                )
                const dataResponse = await response.json()
                if (response.ok) {
                    setLikeUser(1)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        if (likeUser === 1) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    'http://localhost:4200/api/ficheUser/post/like/' + idUrl,
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            userId: authContext.userId,
                            likes: 0,
                        }),
                    }
                )
                const dataResponse = await response.json()
                if (response.ok) {
                    setLikeUser(0)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you will do this with the `button`'s `onClick` handler, in your code it is called `likeSystem`. Can you post that code?

Comment: There you go. But what I want is for it to be done when the page loads, for all posts to be updated according to the user, and his possible likes on this or that post. On the back side, I retrieve for each post, a table of users who have liked. I think I must now make the comparison on the front side.

Comment: have you tried useeffect() that updates when your local state is updated from the backend?

Comment: That's right. After further research, I think the problem comes from my useState which puts itself in a generalist way. I'll try with the class components, and the this operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic error actually. I just had to do, before launching a POST request for likes on the publication targeted by its id, a GET request, with this said id, put my conditions, and the success of each POST request for likes, launch a GET request to retrieve my table of objects from publications, and put this result in the state dedicated to it. Works nickel.

```
    const likeSystem = async (e) => {
        // console.log(e.target.id)
        // let inputLike = document.querySelector('#likeInput')
        // inputLike.value = parseInt(inputLike.value) + 1
        // let iconLikeOn = document.querySelector('#iconLikeOn')
        // iconLikeOn.classList.add('iconLikeOn')

        let idUrl = e.target.id

        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'http://localhost:4200/api/ficheUser/post/one/' + idUrl,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                    },
                }
            )
            const dataResponse = await response.json()
            if (response.ok && dataResponse.likes === 0) {
                console.log('a')
                try {
                    const response = await fetch(
                        'http://localhost:4200/api/ficheUser/post/like/' +
                            idUrl,
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                userId: authContext.userId,
                                likes: 1,
                            }),
                        }
                    )
                    const dataResponse = await response.json()
                    if (response.ok) {
                        fetch(urlGet, {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                            },
                        })
                            .then((resp) => resp.json())
                            .then((data) => setDataResultPosts([...data]))
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            } else if (response.ok && dataResponse.likes === 1) {
                console.log('b')
                try {
                    const response = await fetch(
                        'http://localhost:4200/api/ficheUser/post/like/' +
                            idUrl,
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                userId: authContext.userId,
                                likes: 0,
                            }),
                        }
                    )
                    const dataResponse = await response.json()
                    if (response.ok) {
                        fetch(urlGet, {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
                            },
                        })
                            .then((resp) => resp.json())
                            .then((data) => setDataResultPosts([...data]))
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    const GetPost = ({ infosPosts, infosPostOne }) => {
        return infosPosts.map((posts) => (
            <div className="allPostsAndModals" key={posts._id}>
                <div className="blockAuthor">
                    <div className="divAuthor">
                        <div className="pictureUserPost">
                            <img src="" className="imageUser"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div className="nameAuthor">
                            {posts.firstname} {posts.lastname}
                        </div>
                        <div className="divIconOptions">
                            <button className="blockIconOptions" >
                                <p className="iconOption">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                                        icon={faEllipsis}
                                        fontSize="36px"
                                    />
                                </p>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="blockContentPost">
                    <div className="paragraphContentPost">
                        {posts.postContent} {posts.id}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="separator"></div>
                <div className="blockImagePost">
                    <img
                        className="imagePost"
                        src={posts.imageUrlPostPicture || ' '}
                        alt="photo profil utilisateur"
                    ></img>
                </div>
                <div className="separator"></div>
                <div className="ContenairOptions">
                    <div className="iconLikeOn">
                        <button className="buttonLike" onClick={likeSystem}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                id={posts._id}
                                icon={farThumbsUp}
                            />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {<p>{posts.likes} </p>}
                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try two things:

1. add the `dataIsLoading` element to the `useEffect()` dependency array so your the hook runs when that prop changes.
2. use `forEach` iterator instead of the `for (let arrayOfLikes of dataResultPosts) {` method.

```js
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);

let newArray = [];

function findDataResult(el, idx, arr) {
  console.log({ el, idx, arr });

  // this might be a typo - but I can't tell where dataResult is coming from. 
  let userId = el.find((id) => id === dataResult.infos._id);
  if (userId) {
    setLiked(true);
    console.log('yes');
  } else if (!userId) {
    setLiked(false);
    console.log('no');
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isDataLoading) {
    dataResultPosts.forEach((likeArr) => newArray.push(likeArr.usersLiked));
    newArray.forEach(findDataResult);
  }
}, [isDataLoading]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I look at that and tell you. dataResult, is the result of my GET API request to retrieve the user's info, and dataResultPosts, my GET API request to retrieve all the posts and their info, this, to make the famous comparison between the table of users who liked the post, and the id of the connected user.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work either. Same result. If I like one of the posts, all of them start to true, if I post a new one, all of them go to false. On the console, there is a difference between yes and no on the posts concerned. It's this state that changes everything in a generalized way, and I don't know how to get around that. I also tried with class components, same, nothing that changes.

Comment: After some tests on console, the problem comes that the loop, following any event, takes me only the first or last id I know more, but only one. I do not see how to solve this problem at all.

Comment: And this, any loop. Find(), I think he stops the search as soon as he finds a match. But for of(), forEach, map(), nothing works for moin code.